# html5 localstorage sql, request for searching

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, mobile

i am wondering if the "LIKE '%pattern%' is available in the sql like html5 request storage engine?

i would like to implement a local search to know which embedded html pages to display in a full offline mobile web application...

exemple :
A.html -> "info about A"
B.html -> "info about B"

a search input combobox, the user type "A", then a sql request is done with like "%A%"
Then all matched results are displayed, then the user select the page he really wants, then the page is displayed...

Have you any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you just need something like this.

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-search.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the localStorage is not searchable with conditions like a SQL database is, and this is something that is probably going to be addressed by IndexedDB when it is finally implemented.

The best seems to be to loop over all `localStorage` items and then try to match each key or value using a regex. Like so:

```
for (var i = 0, i < window.localStorage.length, i++) {
    index = window.localStorage.key(i);
    if (index.match(/^string/)) {
        // your code...
    }
}
```